# What regular expression does Facebook use to parse the 'fields' parameter?

Tags: regex, facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api

We are currently working on improving our REST API and we need to implement the optional 'fields' parameter for some actions. Therefore, we would like it to recognize the pattern of the request in the same manner [Facebook is currently doing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/)

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=name,birthday,photos.limit(10).fields(id, picture)
```

After some google searches, we didn't find anything.
So far, we came to this (incomplete) solution:

```
(?<expr>(?&term)(?:[,](?&term))*){0}
(?<term>(?&value)(?:[.](?&mod))*){0}
(?<mod>(limit|fields)\((?&expr)\)){0}
(?<value>\w*){0}
^(?&expr)$
```

The semantic and syntax used is PCRE with the modifier x (PCRE_EXTENDED)

Completely different solutions are also more than welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will that expression ever match anything? Looks like you have made it match nothing but null.

Comment: The above is a incomplete solution, i provided that just in case you'd prefer to work starting from the same point.

Comment: Are you trying to match the string you provided?

Comment: Only the string that define the `fields` parameter: `name,birthday,photos.limit(10).fields(id,picture)`. In any case, our request url string is very similar to Facebook's one above.

Comment: What language are you doing this in? Whats the allowed syntax of this parameter? Can you give more samples to work against?

Comment: Updated the description of this thread (PCRE with the modifier x, PCRE_EXTENDED)